# Windows Forms: ToolStripDropDown - Remove or Paint border

Tags: forms, winforms, renderer

I have a ToolStripDropDown control labeled 'options' here:

[image]

I want to either remove the border or paint it a certain color to make it flush. Do I need a new renderer or something to do this? I've been unable to find an example online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to make your own renderer:

```
public class BorderlessRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer {

  public BorderlessRenderer () {
    RoundedEdges = false;
  }

  protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e) {
    //base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
  }
}
```

Then apply it to your ToolStrip control:

```
toolStrip1.Renderer = new BorderlessRenderer();
```

Comment: When I do this, I see that the constructor is called, but none of the "OnRender..." methods every get called. I even try hitting Refresh() on the toolstrip.

Comment: @RedLeader I just tested it, and my debugger stops at the OnRenderToolStripBorder line.  Make sure you have the toolstrip's Renderer property set to use the custom class.

Comment: Thanks for  your help. I made a more in depth post for this issue of not firing on the methods here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193943/toolstriprenderer-not-firing-virtual-methods . Just to confirm, I do make the assignment.